# How to find relation between two columns of csv (containing labels and related data) file using doc2vec?

Tags: tags, keyword, label, word2vec, doc2vec

I am working on a problem related to doc2vec where i need to find labels that are related to a particular word. For ex (csv file):

```
                         Data                                      Label / Tags
```

```
In a future world devastated by disease, a convict is sent back      sci-fi 
in time to gather information about the man-made virus that 
wiped out most of the human population on the planet.

You have slipped under my skin, invaded my blood and seized my       action
heart. That sounds more like a poison than a person,” was all I 
could say. His confession had both shocked and thrilled me.
```

Plenty of data like this is available on which the model can be trained. Now, I want the results like, when I enter a particular word like **virus**, it gives me corresponding labels (**sci-fi**) where ever the word is used and also give those labels (**action**), where the word **virus** itself is not present but it's semantically related words (like **poison, poisonous**) are present. The semantically related words can be easily fetched from the model. I just want to list the labels.

I want to know if something could be applied rather than using **keyword search**. Any particular method which could help me solve this problem.

Thanks